# Confused about one Concept

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, soft-question

Today in my differential equation lecture, the teacher begin to write some examples in which differential equations appear, first begin with the classic example of a rocket, the example of the mass and the resort, and then he request to us give to he a example of a family of lines, and I tell to he

$y=mx+b$ where $m,b$ are parameters and then he put
$\frac{dy}{dx}=m$ and then he remplaze it in the original equation
$y=\frac{dy}{dx}x+b$
and put that this are the "Equivalent differential form of the family of curves.

Then he  put an exercise and exactlly say the following

Consider $y=A \sin x+ B \cos x$ familly of curves with two parameters $A,B$.Find it´s equivalent differential form.

I Never watch these kind of substitution in my life, and since he say that is a differential form I´m confused because the differential form of one equation is an expression like a $dz=f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy$

Is correct the teacher or it´s wrong, in the second case, can someone explain me or put the name of the concept.

I think that is wrong with the word differential form because if I don´t make a mistake
the differential of the equation $y=mx+b$ is $dy=mdx$

Comment: Your question remains unclear; is your question about how to find the differential form of $y=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$? If so, then what you wrote in the last sentence is the way to answer.

Comment: I want to know if the expression $y=\frac{dy}{dx}m+b$ is a differential form of the family of lines, and if is true I wan´t to know how to get the differential form of $y=A sinx+ Bcos x$ or if the teachers make a mistake, then know how to nombrate to the process of remplaze a parameter for a expression like $\frac{dy}{dx}$ on the equation of the family of lines

Comment: And sorry if I can´t be clear expressing my question, I´m learning English and its hard to me at this moment write clear.

Comment: And how to call to the process of do $y=\frac{dy}{dx}x+b$ that my teacher apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your teacher referred to $y=\frac{dy}{dx}X + b$ as the "differential form" of $y=mx + b$, and given that you're just encountering some simple differential equations, as a way of introducing differential equations, I think you're hearing a false similarity.  The teacher should have more correctly said the "differential *equation* form", and either wasn't thinking of differential forms or didn't know about them.  All the teacher is looking to do (and we can tell from the beginning and result) is to show $y=mx+b$ as a differential equation.  We do that by differentiating, in order to find an equivalent expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and somehow work that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ back into the original equation.

Thus, what your teacher would be expecting (if I'm right) is that you express

$$
y=A\sin x + B\cos x
$$

as a differential equation.  Differentiate once or twice to get an expression  in terms of a derivative that you can substitute back into this equation.

Comment: You clarify all.thanks so much.

Comment: Then my teacher wants that I find A and B in terms of the derivatives I'm  right ?

Comment: It will become more obvious after you start working those derivatives.  Try it out and then post in your ideas.  You may be surprised at how much ends up getting replaced.

Comment: The differential equation whose solution are the expression is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-y$?

Comment: There seems to be a trailing negative after the question mark, but yes, that looks right.  Good job :)

Comment: There are my solution as you said https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993669/find-the-differential-equation-form-of-a-sin-x-b-cos-x

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
y&=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)\\
\frac{d}{dx}(y)&=\frac{d}{dx}(A\sin(x)+B\cos(x))\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=A\frac{d\sin(x)}{dx}+B\frac{d\cos(x)}{dx}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=A\cos(x)-B\sin(x)\\
dy&=(A\cos(x)-B\sin(x))dx
\end{align*}
Therefore :
$$
dy-(A\cos(x)-B\sin(x))dx=0
$$
Is the equivalent differential form of $y$

Comment: Nice I do the same thing, but is possibly do a similar thing like the example of the line where my teacher put the parameter $m$ is terms of the derivatives?

Comment: You wrote in your comments $y=\frac{dy}{dx}m+b$ which I believe is a typo? did you mean $y=\frac{dy}{dx}x+b$? if so then all you do is multiply this equation by $dx$, and you are done.

Comment: Yes is a Typo error, sorry

Comment: Thanks for you explanation I can Understand